# "Largest range" - what is the time complexity?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, time-complexity

I did the question "Largest range" from algoexpert.io. The question is to find the longest range of integers in the array and print an array with the first int and the last int in this range. I wrote the code successfully but I'm new at this algorithm topic and I'm having trouble understanding what is the time complexity of my own code, is it `O(n**2)` or is it `O(n)` because we only go for every num in the array once.

```
def largestRange(array): 
    ans = []
    array = sorted(array)
    while array: 
        size = len(array) 
        start = end = 0
        range_len = 0
        for i in range(size-1): 
            if array[i] == array[i+1]:
                end += 1
                continue
            if array[i] + 1 != array[i+1]:
                break
            range_len += 1
            end += 1

        if not ans or range_len > ans[1] - ans[0]:
            ans = [array[start], array[end]]
        start = end + 1
        array = array[start:]
    return ans
```

this is the [link](https://www.algoexpert.io/questions/Largest%20Range) to the problem if you need to check it:

Comment: Since you've sorted the array, it can't be ```O(N)```. Has to be minimum ```O(NLogN)```

Answer (score 1):

> I'm having trouble understanding what is the time complexity of my own code, is it `O(n*2)` or is it `O(n)`

O(2n) and O(n) are the same, so that question does not make sense.

As pointed out in [Abhinav Mathur's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64422193/largest-range-what-is-the-time-complexity#comment113914643_64422193), it *cannot possibly be* better than O(n log n) because you are using `sorted`, which is a comparison-based sort, and comparison-based sorting has a lower bound of O(n log n).

The body of your `while` loop is executed on the order of `n` times, and at the end of the loop body, you copy the array, which is O(n), therefore the time complexity has to be *at least* O(n²).

Comment: yes sorry I meant to write O(n**2), not O(n*2). O(n) is better than O(n log n)?